# Superset: Remove leading @usernames from string?

Tags: sql, regex, apache-superset

In Superset's SQL Editor, I have a column with string values of which some start with one or more usernames followed by a blank space, followed by the actual text.

```
@usern1 @user2 then some text
```

How can I remove them? so I tried this which did not work:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\s)+', '')
```

Thx!

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '^ *(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ +)+', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to match the leading text.

```
^(?:@[^ ]+ )+
```